# Compute linear regression estimators with the moments method

Tags: equation-solving, probability-or-statistics, summation

I would like to solve this system

```
hyp1 = Sum[Subscript[y, i] - Subscript[\[Beta], 0] - Subscript[\[Beta], 1], {i,1, n}]
hyp2 = Sum[Subscript[x,i]*(Subscript[y, i] - Subscript[\[Beta], 0] - Subscript[\[Beta],1]), {i, 1, n}]
Solve[{hyp1 == 0, hyp2 == 0}, {Subscript[\[Beta], 0],Subscript[\[Beta], 1]}]
```

But

> This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

What function should I use? Thanks

Comment: I think you want to multiply $\beta_1$ by $x_i$ in both equations.  Also so that you see what Mathematica can and cannot do, you might try fixing $n=10$ (or some other positive integer greater than 2) and see what comes out.  Otherwise, $\beta_0+\beta_1$ is really just a single parameter.

Comment: @Artes, do you know how to do it in Mathematica?

Comment: @Jim Baldwin, I'll try restraining n, thanks for the constructive answer.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica seems to make this unreasonably difficult, and won't automatically move factors outside sums or distribute them over `Plus`.  Here is a way to solve the equations for generic `n`.

First define our equations (I've added $x_i$ as spotted by @Jim Baldwin), simplifying as we go

```
dist = Distribute[#, Plus, Sum] &
rule = HoldPattern[Sum[u_?(FreeQ[#, i] &) v_, w__]] :> u Sum[v, w]
hyp1 = (Sum[Subscript[y, i] - b0 - b1 Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, n}] // 
    dist) //. rule
hyp2 = (Sum[
     Expand[Subscript[x, 
        i]*(Subscript[y, i] - b0 - b1 Subscript[x, i])], {i, 1, n}] //
     dist) //. rule
```

Then there is no trouble in solving the equations

```
Solve[{hyp1 == 0, hyp2 == 0}, {b0, b1}] // Simplify
```

I think you have to be pretty dedicated to go through this, but I have found it useful in the past and have derived results that are far more complicated.

**Edit**

To understand the effect of these various functions, consider one of our starting expressions

```
Sum[Subscript[x, i]*(Subscript[y, i] - b0 - b1 Subscript[x, i]), {i, 
  1, n}]
```

The problem is that the coefficients we wish to solve for (`b0` and `b1`) are inside the summation, where `Solve` does not have access to them.  Our first step is to expand the expression inside the summation.  We could do this as

```
% /. Sum[u_, v_] :> Sum[Expand[u], v]
```

We now need to split this into a number of sums.  This can be done using

```
Distribute[%, Plus, Sum]
```

We can now take the factors independent of `i` outside the summation

```
% /. Sum[u_?(FreeQ[#, i] &) v_, w__] :> u Sum[v, w]
```

This is now in a form where `Solve` has access to the variables of interest.

(Note have I avoided subscripted variables everywhere they are not strictly necessary, because I generally find them more trouble than they are worth).

Comment: Your solution works nicely, but unfortunately I'm too much of a beginner to understand this code. Particularly, what is the use of `HoldPattern` here? Thanks

Comment: You can find out by omitting it!  If you do, you'll discover that it doesn't actually make any difference (in this case).  `HoldPattern` means that it doesn't get evaluated before Mathematica tries to match it.  In this case I was being over-cautious, but sometimes evaluating the summation will change its form.

Comment: Ok so what's making a difference here is that you specify to the software that it has to distribute in the ordre "Plus" and then "Sum"? That's it? Thanks for your help btw

Comment: @EBassal I've added more explanation - though you've probably worked it out for yourself by now.